# Reading GRiB2 files using NCTOOLBOX in Matlab,

Tags: matlab, grid, grib

I try to open CFSR gridded binary edition 2 (grb2) precipitation file downloaded from ucar.edu using NCTOOLBOX. However I got error messages:

```
"nc=ncgeodataset('prate.gdas.200812.grb2')
Error using ncdataset (line 91)
Failed to open prate.gdas.200812.grb2

Error in cfdataset (line 59)
        obj = obj@ncdataset(url);

Error in ncgeodataset (line 74)
        obj = obj@cfdataset(url);

Caused by:
    Undefined variable "ucar" or class "ucar.nc2.dataset.NetcdfDataset.openDataset".
```

Can anyone please debug what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for this stupid question, but are you sure that you have been setup NCTOOLBOX in a correct way? Because I had the same problem until I was setup it how it says here  http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/recipes/?q=recipes/How-to-Read-GLDAS-or-NLDAS-GRIB-formatted-Data-with-MATLAB-0
Good luck!